# $F$ is an increasing function and $F(0) > 0$. For $x \geq 0$, define $G(x) = \int_{0}^{x} F$. Prove that $G$ is one-to-one

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, proof-writing

I am given a practice question where I am supposed to show that the function of G is one-to-one. Where $G(x) = \int_{0}^{x} F$, where $F$ is an increasing function and $F(0)>0$.

I thought about thinking about the second part of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but I don't know if that is the right method to show that the function is one to one. Also, I don't know if I can just say

> Suppose that $F(0) = 1$ since $F(0) > 0$, then $G(x) = F(x) - 1$.

Any help will be great.

Edit: It was clarified that $x \geq 0$

Comment: I'm assuming we're only considering $x \geq 0$? Because otherwise $F(0) > 0$ doesn't really help with negative $x$ values.

Comment: Let F(t)=2t+1, then G(x)=x^2+x which is not one to one. I think you may be missing some of the question.

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh Nope, this is the question that was given. No specific functions were given.

Comment: My prof clarified it that $x \geq 0$. I edited the question above.

Answer (score 2):

I would think this is a proof by contradiction:

Let's assume $G(x)$ is *not* one-to-one. Therefore there exists two different $x$ values, $x_1 < x_2$ such that $G(x_1) = G(x_2)$:

\begin{align*}
G(x_1) =&\ \int\limits_0^{x_1}F(t)dt \\
G(x_2)=&\ \int\limits_0^{x_2}F(t)dt = \int\limits_0^{x_1}F(t)dt + \int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2}F(t)dt = G(x_1) + \int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2}F(t)dt
\end{align*}

If $G(x_1) = G(x_2)$ then $\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2}F(t)dt = 0$. You need to show that this isn't possible if $x_2 > x_1$ and $F(t)$ is increasing.

**Edit (clarification of my comment):**

This question was edited (which is fine and is good), but I do want to explain for anyone curious why we *need* $x \geq 0$ for the given problem statement.

If we are *only* given that $F(t)$ is monotonically increasing and $F(0) > 0$, that's not enough to conclude that $G(x) = \int\limits_0^xF(t)dt$ is one-to-one.

Consider the following:

$$
F(t) = 4t^3 + 2t + 1
$$

Clearly $F(0) = 1 > 0$ and it's clearly monotonically increasing (not even just monotonically non-decreasing--$F'(t) = 12t^2 + 2 > 0$ for all $t$)

$$
G(x) = \int\limits_0^xF(t)dt = x^4 + x^2 + x
$$

A simple graph of this function will show that it *is* one-to-one when $x\geq0$, in fact it's one-to-one for all $x \geq \xi$ such that $4\xi^3 + 2\xi + 1 = 0$, but if we allow a domain such that $\xi - \delta < x < \infty$, where $\delta > 0$, then it's clearly *not* one-to-one.

Which brings me to my ultimate criticism (of the question): we *don't* need $F(0) > 0$, we *only* need $F(0) \geq 0$ and $x \geq 0$. With that constraint I can easily explain the requirement for $x \geq 0$:

$$
F(t) = 4t^3 + 2t \rightarrow G(x) = \int\limits_0^xF(t)dt = x^4 + x^2
$$

This is $F(t)$, an odd function (and is clearly monotonically increasing), results in a even function: cannot possibly be one-to-one unless we restrict to $x \geq 0$.

**Please Note:** I'm talking about a "counterexample" as to why we *must* have $x \geq 0$ (i.e. a function, $F(t)$, that is monotonically increasing that does *not* result in a one-to-one function if $x < 0$)! This does *not* mean $F(t)$ needs to be odd--only monotonically increasing on the interval $0 < t < \infty$, with $F(0) \geq 0$ *and* $x \geq 0$.

**Second Note: $F(t)$ is monotonically increasing but $F(0) < 0$:** (assuming $x \geq 0$)

Simple counterexample:

$$
F(t) = 4(t - 1)^3 \rightarrow G(x) = \int\limits_0^xF(t)dt = (x - 1)^4 - 1
$$

Here $G(x)$ is *not* one-to-one because you get $G(0) = G(2) = 0$

Answer (score 2):

Use the fondamental theorm of aclculus to obtain
$$G'(x)=F(x).$$ Since $F$ is increasing, we have $G(x)=F(x)>0$ for all $x\geq0$. That means $G'>0$ and so $G$ is strictly increasing (meaning $a>b$ implies $G(a)>G(b)). A strictly increasing function is one to one.

Comment: We only know $F$ is increasing. FTOC needs stronger hypotheses.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating under integral sign we have $G'(x)=f(x)>0$ as f(x) is an increasing function. Thus G(x) is an increasing function. We need to prove its montonically increasing for itto become one-to-one. Let's say for some interval $x_{0}-x_{1}$ f(x) has same value then $G(x_{0})=\int_0^{x_0} f(x)=H(x_{0})$. Now $G(x_{1})=H(x_{0})+\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}} f(x)$ but as we have assumed that here f(x) is constant and let it be equal to c.
we have $G(x_{1})=H(x_{0})+(x_{1}-x_{0})c$. Now I have assumed $x_1>x_0$ also c is >0 as f(x) is increasing and f(0)>0 . So $(x_1-x_0)c>0$. Hence $G(x)$ is one to one function.

Comment: G'(x) may be negative for negative values of x.

Comment: Yeah I wrongly differentiated this should fix it.

Comment: I don't think differentiating is justified, we are only given that $F$ is increasing.